# Check who have changed build quality value in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am investigating such a thing: do I have possibility to see who have changed build quality value in TFS? I have red a lot of publications and materials about EventService in TFS. With this service I can listen to BuildQualityValueChangedEvent and trigger some actions when Build Qaulity changes. I want to do the following:

1. Listen to BuildQualityValueChangedEvent.
2. Obtain information about user who changed it.

After all researches I've done I can make a conclusion that this task can be done by writing specific TFS plugin that will query information from SQL database, where information about build quality changes stored. Here is the question: **where does TFS stores information from BuildQualityValueChangedEvent event? Does anybody have any suggestions how to get username of person who changed Build Quality Value?**

UPDATE 1
I used code like this to get my subscriptions info

```
IEventService eventService = (IEventService)tfServer.GetService(typeof(IEventService));
Subscription[] subscriptions = eventService.GetAllEventSubscriptions(userName);
List<Subscription> list = new List<Subscription>();
```

But I haven't got the information that I wanted to get. I've red that there is **BuildStatusChangeEvent** Class that contains all information that I need about build. Do you know how to use it? Maybe some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this through the API available in ISubscriber. The Xml event data that you are passed will have that information in it and you can parse it and log it.

To do this you need to implement the ISubscriber interface. I have an old example in VB from 2010 but it should give you a starting point:

- http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/

Within the body of the NotifyEvent method you will be able to access information about who is making the changes by parsing out the "notificationEventArgs" xml into a BuildQualityChangedNotificationEvent object.

Answer (score 0):

After more researches done I've found DB table that contains such an information. Its name is dbo.tbl_ClientEvent. This info is like "<"ChangedBy">" TFSSERVER\user"<"/""ChangedBy">"

Comment: Do not interact directly with the TFS operational databases. This can leave your server in an unsuportable state even if you are only reading data. TFS databases have been highly optimized by the product team and you may inadvertently cause performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wanted to figure out if this record exists in TFS DB. I will interact with it through API.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the table you are looking at gets cleaned regularly. There is no built in audit trail for who changed the build quality so you will need to log it yourself.